# Hive. Can not refer to partitions in where clause

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive

I create a table partitioned by date. But can not use the partition in where clause. 
Here is the process
step1:

```
     CREATE TABLE new_table (
           a string,
           b string
      )
     PARTITIONED BY (dt string);
```

Step2:

```
        Insert overwrite table new_table partition (dt=$date)
        Select a, b from my_table
        where dt = '$date
```

---

Table is created.

```
           Describe new_table;
           a string
           b string
           dt string
```

*Problem*:

```
           select * from new_table where dt='$date'
```

returns empty set.

whereas

```
            select * from new_table
```

returns a, b, and dt.

Does anyone know what might be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you run `SHOW PARTITIONS new_table;`?

Comment: Tried, but was unable to reproduce your problem; did several permutations, including dynamic partitions. As already suggested, verify your queries, check partitions, etc.

Comment: my bad, I was doing;
> hive -e 'select * from new_table where dt='$date'' 
and single quotes were causing the problem. I took me 3 hours to see this:) thanks for the answers though

Answer (score 0):

Sahara, partitions in where clause do work. Any chance you are specifying the wrong value in the RHS of your predicate?

You may also want to see the data inside `/user/hive/warehouse/new_table` (by default) to see if the data there looks the way you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting with

```
Insert overwrite table new_table partition (dt=$date)
    Select a, b, dt from my_table
    where dt = '$date'
```